# copy media files from iPod library to an app

Tags: iphone

I am thinking about app which should play audio files placed in iPod library and played by Audio Units to make sure that IO has the lowest possible latency. As I know I cannot use standard way because direct iPod library playing is supported only within AVFoundation.

So my question is, if there is any possible way to copy picked media files into an app and then play them by audio units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve written some sample code that does this: https://github.com/davidcairns/MediaPlayerDemo

Comment: cool, works fine, it is bit lazy, but testing just with iPod4. iPhone5 should make it reasonably fast. I will try to thing about possible optimization.

Comment: Good stuff, Thanks David. It looks like it can export and convert audio into caf at the same time, which is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/62807-export-audio-m4a-alac.html